# Reading Elements by attribute Condition lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Using lxml libarary how can I read element value if an attribute is given.
For example if "qtn" state=2 then return value required is "Doctor Checkup"

Thanks. If possible please also give me any tutorial/url for the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<elements>
<qtn state="1">I have severe chest pain
    <an state="2" res="a">Check Up</an>
</qtn>
<qtn state="2">Doctor checkup
    <an state="9" res="a">Recovered</an>
    <an state="3" res="b">Blood Test</an>
    <an state="8" res="c">Untreatable</an>
</qtn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.parse(open('1.xml'))
xml.xpath("//qtn[@state="+state+"]/text()")
```